# GNS construction and representations

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

I am currently reading about C* from the following notes
( [http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C%2A-algebras.pdf](http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C*-algebras.pdf) ).

In the proof of GNS construction theorem 1.12.4 page 50 there is something I don't understand in particular 3 that it defines a bounded linear operator on $H_{\phi}$ if we have the following

$\|\pi_{\phi}(a)(b + N_{\phi})\|^2 = \langle[ab],[ab]\rangle = \phi((ab)^{*}ab) = \phi(b^{*}a^{*}ab) \leq ||a||^{2}||b + N_{\phi}||^{2}$

Is the reason it is continous is because it is bounded for every choice of ab ? can someone explain as to why its continous in details ? since this is the only part I don't understand in the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator you are defining is $\pi_\phi(a)$ for a fixed $a$. The inequality you posted shows that $\pi_\phi(a)$ is bounded on the subspace of elements of the form $b+N_\phi$, for all $b$. A bounded operator is continuous.

Comment: Nice to see you here prof @Martin Argerami !

Comment: I would like to add one can actually picture it as follows is if you bound your operator for all elements so it doesn't really explode anywhere as it moves between its values.

Comment: No intuition necessary,  this is very concrete: if $\|Tx\|\leq c\|x\|$ for all $x $, then $$\|Tx-Ty\|=\|T (x-y)\|\leq c\|x-y\|, $$ which tells you that given $\varepsilon >0$ for the definition of continuity, you can take  $\delta=\varepsilon /c$.

Comment: I see thank alot